# Does class order matter when trying to select an element?

Tags: jquery

Say I have an element that has three classes:

```
<div class="one two three"></div>
```

If I want to select this element using the classes, and I do:

```
$('.three.two.one').addClass('four');
```

instead of:

```
$('.one.two.three').addClass('four');
```

Will it work regardless the order of the classes?

Comment: You should have just tried it.  It only takes a minute, gurl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the solution will work for current scenario.

However using the selector in ordered sequence is faster when compared to unordered sequence.

**[HERE IS THE PERFORMANCE TEST](http://jsperf.com/multiple-class-selector)**

Comment: Performance difference?  I tried three browsers in your test and see no meaningful or consistent difference.

Comment: @jfriend00: i have tested it on chrome. and it works.

Comment: Sure it works.  But there's no meaningful performance difference between the order or unordered options in any browser.  So, I don't see any evidence that order affects performance.  Thus, I don't agree with your conclusion that one is faster than the other.

Answer (score 2):

### No, it doesn't matter.

That is the answer and cannot be explained more and this shouldn't be a comment because this *is* the answer.